# How to add Objective-C code to Nativescript Plugin?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nativescript

I am trying to write a NativeScript plugin which requires some Objective-C code. I've read the article [Adding Objective-C Code to a NativeScript App](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/adding-objective-c-code-to-a-nativescript-app) which clearly shows how to add Objective-C code in my application and I've gotten this to work. However I want to implement this code in the plugin itself. I've tried putting the Objective-C code in `myplugin/src/App_Resources/iOS/src/mycode.swift` but it never gets copied to my application.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you like to access swift class it must be exposed to objective c with `@objc` attribute.

Comment: @Manoj, yes I understand this. I would like to include a .swift file in my plugin which exposes swift source code from a cocoapod that is missing this annotation. But .swift files places in `myplugin/src/App_Resources/iOS/src` aren't copied to my application.

Comment: I would suggest doing this in a separate plugin and see this: https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries

Comment: @Naxos84 I've read that documentation, its how I installed the cocoapod I'm trying to wrap. I think what your suggesting is building an iOS plugin which imports the cocoapod I'm trying to wrap, plus the wrapping swift code, and use that as an NS plugin in my app?

Comment: yes. Write an iOS swift plugin (with all necessary annotations like @objc etc.) then include this "native" plugin inside a nativescript-plugin.

Comment: I have the same problem as you. I have a swift file  (with all necessary annotations) that wraps the cocoapod I need to use. It's work fine in a regular nativescript app (inside App_Resources/iOS/src folder). But it does not work in a nativiscript plugin. I see that one solution is to inlclude a "native" plugin inside my nativescript-plugin. But I don't how to implement it. So, please could you help me?